# R help - Error: `rows` must be `NULL` or a `vars()` list if `cols` is a `vars()` list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like help understanding the following error when using ggplot2 facet_wrap

```
Error: `rows` must be `NULL` or a `vars()` list if `cols` is a `vars()` list
```

I'm using fresh installs on a new computer. And am now getting the error on any data frames I try to plot. For example

test.csv

```
party,status,emissions
Australia,low,20
Australia,mid,30
Australia,high,40
Finland,low,60
Finland,mid,10
Australia,high,45
```

R

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

test <- read.csv("test.csv")

test %>% ggplot() + geom_path(aes(status,emissions)) %>% 
  facet_grid(vars(party))
  #or facet_wrap(~party)
```

Comment: The last line should be `+` instread of `%>%` i.e. `test %>% ggplot() + geom_path(aes(status,emissions)) + facet_grid(vars(party))`

Comment: How embarrassing! I've been scratching my head for hours. Thank you so much

Comment: You can't use the pipe `%>%` within `ggplot2` - switch to using `+` so it'd be:
`test %>% ggplot() + geom_path(aes(status,emissions)) + 
  facet_grid(vars(party))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We need `+` instead of `%>%`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
test %>%
    ggplot() + 
      geom_path(aes(status,emissions)) + 
      facet_grid(.~ party)
```